# Collapsible App Bar Elevation Issue With Support Library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have been having a problem with the App Bar in the new Material Design Support Library. My issue is that the CollapsingToolbarLayout is at a different elevation than that of the top part of the Toolbar. Here is my XML code for the layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:elevation="25dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.example.example.widgets.CustomImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            ...>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    .../>

                <TextView
                    .../>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    ... />
```

Here is my `onCreate` Java code for the Activiy:

```
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_write);

    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("App Name");

    collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Title");
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.LargeText);
}
```

Finally, here is a screenshot of my problem:

[image: Image 1]

Again the issue is the bottom half of the bar (The collapsing part) not being at the same elevation. Any advice on how to fix this would be great!

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**

Here is my updated activity image:

[image: Image 2]

*All content except the title is now gone*

Answer (score 0):

I think the theme you're applying to this Activity already has an ActionBar. Use NoActionBar themes if you want to use ToolBar and want to set it as an ActionBar.

Comment: How can I do this and keep the title and drop down menu that the app bar has?

Comment: Apply Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar to this Activity in Android manifest file and set your Toolbar as ActionBar using setSupportActionBar method.

Comment: This works great, but now my AppBar is not displaying my back button or any of my menu items...

Comment: Are you calling setSupportActionBar method ?

Comment: Yes. Now my action bar is displaying properly, but all my content is gone exept for the title (which i set on the collapsing toolbar layout). Is there a way for me to set my menu items and back button on my toolbar or collapsingToolbarLayout?

Comment: You've commented out setSupportActionBar call which is required.

Comment: I forgot to update that part in my question. With my project have used setSupportActionBar

Comment: In my second picture you can see that the app bar is displaying properly, but without any of the menu buttons or back button, etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a CollapsingToolbar you don't have to set up the title in the ActionBar, it's only setted in CollapsingToolbar

```
//This one is not needed
//getSupportActionBar().setTitle("App Name");

collapsingToolbar.setTitle("App Name");
```